# Selecting every second and third element in a 4 column grid

Tags: css

I'm looking to select the middle elements in my grid. I'm not particularly great at `nth` selectors so I'm at a loss here. What would be the best approach to select elements: 2+3, 6+7, 10+11, 14+15.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
 flex-basis: 25%;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">1</div>
  <div class="flex-child">2</div>
  <div class="flex-child">3</div>
  <div class="flex-child">4</div>
  <div class="flex-child">5</div>
  <div class="flex-child">6</div>
  <div class="flex-child">7</div>
  <div class="flex-child">8</div>
  <div class="flex-child">9</div>
  <div class="flex-child">10</div>
  <div class="flex-child">11</div>
  <div class="flex-child">12</div>
  <div class="flex-child">13</div>
  <div class="flex-child">14</div>
  <div class="flex-child">15</div>
  <div class="flex-child">16</div>
  <div class="flex-child">17</div>
  <div class="flex-child">18</div>
  <div class="flex-child">19</div>
  <div class="flex-child">20</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  width: 400px;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
 flex-basis: 25%;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(4n+2),.flex-child:nth-child(4n+3) {
   background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">1</div>
  <div class="flex-child">2</div>
  <div class="flex-child">3</div>
  <div class="flex-child">4</div>
  <div class="flex-child">5</div>
  <div class="flex-child">6</div>
  <div class="flex-child">7</div>
  <div class="flex-child">8</div>
  <div class="flex-child">9</div>
  <div class="flex-child">10</div>
  <div class="flex-child">11</div>
  <div class="flex-child">12</div>
  <div class="flex-child">13</div>
  <div class="flex-child">14</div>
  <div class="flex-child">15</div>
  <div class="flex-child">16</div>
  <div class="flex-child">17</div>
  <div class="flex-child">18</div>
  <div class="flex-child">19</div>
  <div class="flex-child">20</div>
</div>
```